# change one field in mysql depending on another

Tags: mysql, automation

how can i put together a macro/script/something automatic that will allow me to make the following changes to my database in mass:

if any cell in column 1 is X, then change the contents of column 2 (in the same row) to 0.
if the cell in column 1 is not X, then leave the contents of column 2 alone.

Comment: if this 'rule' is supposed to happen all the time - then you may consider a trigger (after you have set the values the way you want in the first place) - the trigger would set the column2 to 0 anytime you saved the row with column1 = X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple `UPDATE` statement with a `WHERE` clause.  Run once to update all rows in your table.

```
UPDATE yourtable SET column2 = 0 WHERE column1 = 'X'
```

If you need to automatically update `column2` to 0 whenever `column1` is changed to `X`, create a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

```
/* DELIMITER has been set to $$ in your client */
CREATE TRIGGER column1_is_X BEFORE UPDATE ON yourtable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.column1 = 'X' THEN
    SET NEW.column2 = 0;
  END IF;
END$$
/* Then you should set the DELIMITER back to ; */
```

Comment: Thank you. And when you say "automatically," is this something I can setup in phpMyAdmin to constantly be running so that I don't have to run this statement every time I want the changes made?

Comment: @user1863562 The TRIGGER will run everytime a row is updated, automatically, and constantly.  To create the trigger in PHPMyAdmin, you probably need to set the delimiter to something else like `$$` temporarily so the trigger will get created. I don't use PMA, so I don't know the exact procedure.  Above, I edited the statement to end with `$$`, assuming that's what you set the delimiter to.

Comment: Ran your trigger script and got this error:
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF; END' at line 6"

Comment: Thank you. One last question about a variance -- instead of column1 = X, how do I change it so that it would be if column1 simply contained an X somewhere in the characters? In this case, it would actually be a *, not an X.

Comment: Or in the trigger context `LOCATE(NEW.column1, '*') > 0`

Comment: Didn't know about the LOCATE command. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
UPDATE table SET column2 = IF (column1 = 'X', 0, column2)
```